# Initializing and populating a Python dictionary, key -> List

Tags: python

I have a simple task that comes up often my work. I need to create a dictionary for an id key to a list of data associated with that key. I'm wondering if there is a better way to do this than the one I am using. The pattern is so common that I feel there must be better solution.

```
value_list_dict = {}

for line in f:
  line.strip()
  rec = line.split("\t")
  my_key = rec[0]
  important_value = rec[5] #or what ever it is

  # the repetitive pattern I find myself doing a lot of.
  if my_key not in value_list_dict:
    value_list_dict[my_key] = []
  value_list_dict[my_key].append(important_value)
```

While this solution is fairly concise and clear to me, I wonder if there is a better way.

I think that writing a custom function for this might be less readable although I'm open to suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`line.strip()` does not modify the variable, it returns a modified string. But you can chain it together with the `split`. I would also jchoose a better variable name than `rec`. As J.F.Sebastian suggested in the comments, you could go with `items`:

```
for line in f:
    items = line.strip().split('\t')
```

Your code is the perfect place for a `collections.defaultdict`. You can give it a type which it will use when the key is not defined. It makes implementing a counter a lot easier (just pass it `int`, whose default constructor returns an int with value 0) or, give it `list` and it will give you an empty list:

```
from collections import defaultdict

value_dict = defaultdict(list)

with open("file.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        items = line.strip().split('\t')
        key, value = items[0], items[5]
        value_dict[key].append(value)
```

I also added the `with..as` construct in there, in case you are not yet using it.

In python 3.x I would use the [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/):

```
key, *other_vals, value = line.strip().split('\t')
```

Comment: `line.strip()` was a typo. I usally do `line = line.strip()`. I really like the `defaultdict` solution. I'm not sure what you mean by the advanced unpacking. Does that assume that `value` is the last item in the collection?

Comment: @pbible, yes it does. If there is more stuff coming afterwards, you will have to do it manually, two starred variables won't work.

Comment: I could see how that could be useful.  `key, *other_vals, value = line.strip().split('\t')[:6]` would work, but I'm getting off topic. Thanks, `defaultdict` is the perfect solution I think.

Comment: @pbible yes, that would work, but would defeat some point of having introduced that syntax in the first place (which was making `first, rest = l[0], l[1:]` easier and more efficient), as described in the linked PEP 3132 :)

Comment: thanks for clarifying. There is no guarantee that the needed information will be in a particular place (the beginning or end), as this is a general problem I deal with for many different file types. It's nice to know about this feature though.

Comment: Please, do not use `line` name for the result of the `split()` that is a list (`line` is a string in your code i.e., `line = line.strip()` is ok). One name—one purpose (in the same context). You could use `items`, `fields` names instead. @pbible you could use `key, value = getitems(line.strip().split('\t'))` where `getitems = operator.itemgetter(0,5)`